# Mock an Interface with Mockito return a NullPointerException

Tags: interface, mocking, mockito, powermock

I m trying create unit tests for one project.I m facing a problem because when I try control the result of an interface(mock). When the code get the Interface variable that return a NullPointerException.

Firstly I tried @Override the method in my test class (ClassA), but it don't work. After that I tried mock the interface object and control the comportment with Mockito.When().tehnReturn();

I will put here my code, I read some solutions but none works.

My Interface:

```java
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Interface {
        UpdateXResponse process(UpdateXRequest request) throws Exception;
    }
```

The class I want to test:

```java
    @Service(ClassA.class)
    public class ClassA extends VService implements UpdateX {

        @Reference
        @Inject
        private Interface interface;

        @Inject
        public ClassA(...) {...}

        @Override
        public UpdateXResponse process(UpdateXRequest request) throws Exception {
            UpdateXResponse response = initResponse(context, request, new UpdateXResponse());
            UpdateXInput input = request.getInput();
            UpdateXOutput output = new UpdateXOutput();
            response.setOutput(output);

            try {
                firstMethodCall(...);

            } catch (Exception t) {
                throwCorrectException(t, logger);
            }
            return response;
        }

        private void firstMethodCall(...) throws Exception {
            TypeF typeF = callInterfaceMethod(...);
            ...
        }

        /**
         * Orchestrates Interface service
         */
        protected TypeF callInterfaceMethod(...) {
            ...
            request.setInput(input);
            request.setHeader(header);

            InterfaceResponse response = interface.process(request); // LINE ERROR - In this step interface is NULL when the test get this

            return response;
        }
    }
```

And finally my class test:

```java
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(value = {ClassA.class,Interface.class} )
    public class WithPowerMockUnitTest{

        @InjectMocks
        private ClassA classA;

        private Interface interface;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            InterfaceRequest InterfaceRequest = createInterfaceRequest();
            InterfaceResponse serviceUnavailableResponse = createInterfaceResponse();

            Interface = Mockito.mock(Interface.class);
            when(Interface.process(Mockito.any(InterfaceRequest.class))).thenReturn(serviceUnavailableResponse);  
        }

        @Test
        public void testh() throws SOAException {
            InterfaceResponse res = interface.process(Mockito.any(InterfaceRequest.class)); // There all run ok. The interface is not null and return what i expected.
            System.out.println("RES "+res);
        }
        @Test
        public void test() {
            assertNotNull(classA);  // not null
            assertNotNull(interface); // not null
        }

        @Test
        public void newTest() throws Exception {

            InterfaceRequest InterfaceRequest = createInterfaceRequest();
            InterfaceResponse serviceUnavailableResponse = createInterfaceResponse();

            UpdateXResponse response = ClassA.process(updateXRequest()); // PROBLEM!! When that get the LINE ERROR the interface is null! WHY?      
        }
    }
```

I put some comments in the lines where the problem exists for me.

---

```java
    public interface A{
        Response process(Request r) throws Exception;
    }

    public class B{

    private Class_That_Override_Interface_method  ctoim;

        public Response function(){
          X res = method_B();
        }
        protected X method_B(){
          response res = ctoim.process(request); // That ctoim is always NULL when the test get that line/call
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `@Mock` annotation on your `Interface` variable.
Therefore the mock is not injected into your `classA` and the `newTest()` fails. (In this case remove `Interface = Mockito.mock(Interface.class);` from the `setUp` method).

Alternativly remove the `@InjectMocks` annotation and create your class under test manually passing your mock into the constructor.

---

For this specific case (assuming its a different case from the last question)
there doesn't seem to be a need to involve `PowerMockito`. So unless you left out some relevant parts you might as well just use the `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

---

Ps.:
Also remeber what I said last time about `compilable` examples?

- `interface` is a keyword and can't be used for variables.
- You should also aim to write variables identical all the times (not `Interface` and `interface` / `classA` and `ClassA`)

And in case you haven't read it yet check out the help section about [minmal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

Edit:

I fogot to mention that the line `interface.process(Mockito.any(InterfaceRequest.class));` in `testh()` is actually invalid syntax. You should use `ArgumentMatchers` only for parameters of mocked methods.

Also consider adding the [`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock_annotation) to your `setUp` method, when using the `PowerMockRunner`.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. This time I tried put here all the logic and not the minimal example because I see some identical  one but without success. Next time i will try put some with 'minimal reproducible examples' and sorry for the variable names.

Comment: And I tried with and without the _@Mock_. But if you see in _@before_, i use 'Interface = Mockito.mock(Interface.class);' and i think that inject the mock.

Comment: That only creates the class locally for your test (thats why `testh()` and `test()` work), but has no relation to `classA`.

Comment: Its the same case of last question. For get this line and call the interface i needed to mock 2 dependencies and the last protected method (last question)

Comment: Thanks. I change to without ArgumentMatchers , but still get nullpointerexc. And add the @Mock too. Its possible implements the interface and override the method in my test class? Or, it is not a solution?

Comment: Can you replace your example code with an updated [mre]? I am (again) not sure whether I understand your actual issue.

Comment: If you want to use a manual created class that implements your interface (aka `stub`) you can always do that. But there should be no real difference (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: Im not with the enterprise computer now, so tomorrow i will create one better exemple. But basically the class i want to test is the same of the last question. And after the same method call the protected method of a superclass, he will call the interface method, but it return a nullpointerexception.

Comment: I cant create a minimal executable example now, but i will try to simplified my post

Comment: I little one question, I used the annotation `@InjectMocks
    private A a;`, but in one `@Test` I created an instance for use a Spy(PowerMock) like `a = PowerMockito.spy(new A(params));` It is correct? Can I Create a mock but for a specifically create a spy?!

Comment: You want to say for some tests you want to use the normal class and for one test you want to use a `spy` instead? Yes you can do that, the annotated fields should be automatically reinitialized before every test. However this might make the test hard to read (for other people).

Comment: Yes, that. Thanks. Well, I found where is the problem, but I cant solve this. The interface is one `@Reference` and `@Injected` in runtime, on my test Class. In the test class I use `@InjectMocks` in me classA and `@Mock` in the interface variable. When I run the test, it creat one instance of ClassA and one for Interface variable. But INSIDE of ClassA this variable is null. I will try put one image of this.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6AdF.png) can you see this?

Comment: When the interface method is called, he use the null value.

Comment: What kind of `Injection` are you using? Check the requirements [`here`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).

Comment: For the class I want to test `@InjectMocks` and for the other `@Mock`. I will read that.

Comment: I found the error. I use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and PrepareforTest, but i need MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); too!!!!!!